# Error when retrieve arraylist value in Android

Tags: android

I trying to use bundle to save/retrieve my array list but i get below error when i run it. i receive value from another activity as score and with checking score i changing arraylist value, then save the array list with method `save()` and finally i want retrieve my saved arraylist but it's not working.

```
public class Favorites_page extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

String on="on",off="off";
static TextView tv_fav1,tv_fav2,tv_fav3,tv_fav4,tv_fav5,tv_fav6,tv_fav7,tv_favoritetittle;
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(3);



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.favorites);

    boolean check = list.isEmpty();
    if(check){
        list.add(0,off);list.add(1,off);list.add(2,off);
        save();
         }
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE); 
    int score = pref.getInt("score", 0);
    //
    tv_fav1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_fav1);
    tv_fav2= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_fav2);
    tv_fav3= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_fav3);
    tv_fav4= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_fav4);
    tv_fav5= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_fav5);
    tv_fav6= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_fav6);
    tv_fav7= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_fav7);
    tv_favoritetittle=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_favoritetittle);

    tv_fav1.setOnClickListener(this);
    tv_fav2.setOnClickListener(this);
    tv_fav3.setOnClickListener(this);
    tv_fav4.setOnClickListener(this);
    tv_fav5.setOnClickListener(this);
    tv_fav6.setOnClickListener(this);
    tv_fav7.setOnClickListener(this);


    switch (score) {

    case 99:
        if(score == 99){

            tv_favoritetittle.setText("Nothing");

        }
        break;

    case 100:
        if(score == 100){
            //tv_fav7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            list.set(0,on);
        save();



        }
        break;
case 101:
    if(score == 101){
        //tv_fav6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        list.set(1,on);
        save();



    }
        break;
case 102:
    if(score == 102){
        tv_fav5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        list.set(2,on);
        save();


    }
    break;

    default:
        break;
    }


    Bundle value= new Bundle();
    list=value.getStringArrayList("temp1");

// i recive error in below line......

    String pos=list.get(0);
    if (pos==on) {
        tv_fav7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

 } // marbot be Content 

public void save()
{
    Bundle value= new Bundle();
    value.putStringArrayList("temp1", list);      
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}  // marbot be Activity
```

and this is logcat :

```
05-08 14:58:24.081: E/AndroidRuntime(972): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-08 14:58:24.081: E/AndroidRuntime(972): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.falconteam.zekr/com.falconteam.zekr.Favorites_page}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-08 14:58:24.081: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
05-08 14:58:24.081: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
05-08 14:58:24.081: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-08 14:58:24.081: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
05-08 14:58:24.081: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-08 14:58:24.081: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-08 14:58:24.081: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-08 14:58:24.081: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 14:58:24.081: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-08 14:58:24.081: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-08 14:58:24.081: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-08 14:58:24.081: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-08 14:58:24.081: E/AndroidRuntime(972): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-08 14:58:24.081: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at com.falconteam.zekr.Favorites_page.onCreate(Favorites_page.java:101)
05-08 14:58:24.081: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-08 14:58:24.081: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
```

Comment: remove this line: `list=value.getStringArrayList("temp1")` and it will work

Comment: thank you its work, but why that line not work ?

Comment: `Bundle value= new Bundle();` creates a new Bundle which doesn't contain your list

Comment: this pos=list.get(0); give me updated list ?

Comment: it gives you what you put at index 0 in your ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

Fix this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-08 14:58:24.081: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at com.falconteam.zekr.Favorites_page.onCreate(Favorites_page.java:101)
05-08 14:58:24.081: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-08 14:58:24.081: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
```